# Can you make an objects that deletes itself in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I made model `VerificationToken`

```
class VerificationToken(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    @property
    def expiration(self):

        lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)

        expire = self.date_created + lifetime

        return expire
```

and this model have an expiration property. Is there a way to make this model delete itself after it expires?

Comment: No, better to use something like redis for this. There you can set a time to live (TTL) after which it's simply removed by the system. If you want to use models, you'd have to have a crontab or something running every X-minutes that queries and deletes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a filter that prevents retrieving expired `VerificationToken`s:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

VerificationToken.objects.filter(
    date_created__gte=Now()-timedelta(minutes=10)
)
```

You can also make a manager such that `VerificationToken.objects` is a manager that only contains non-expired tokens:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class VerificationTokenManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_querset().filter(
            date_created__gte=Now()-timedelta(minutes=10)
        )

class VerificationToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    objects = VerificationTokenManager()
```

you can then make a [*management command* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that you for example run through cron, or some other scheduling task that removes expired `VerificationToken`s with:

```
# app_name/management/commands/remove_expired_tokens.py

from datetime import timedelta
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from app_name.models import VerificationToken

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Remove expired verification tokens'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        VerificationToken._base_manager.filter(
            date_created__lt=Now()-timedelta(minutes=10)
        ).delete()
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: in the very first snippet that you show in your answer do you actually mean `lte` or `gte`?

Comment: @Melly: it does not really matter, you can exchange `gte` for `gt` and `lt` for `lte`, but this is a timestamp tick, so the effect will be a *microsecond*, which likely does not matter at all.

Comment: what's the logic of that filter in the `VerificationTokenManager` is it "you have the requirements so you're going pass the filter" or "you have the requirement so you're going to be filtered"?

Comment: @Melly: if you use `VerificationToken.objects`, it will automatically filter such that it only works on valid tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Django does't provide that kind of functionality. You can use Celery to create a celery task that will delete tokens that expires after certain amount of time. Also you can create task that will periodically find expired tokens and will delete them.

[Celery documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible. What you can do is to create a cronjob using celery-beat or what you like and set a cronjob task to clean up expired DB records (once per minute/hour/day)